# Getting boolean value false while applying jsonwebtoken and testing api in POSTMAN

Tags: routes, jwt, postman

- in this project i am testing each route after coding it.when i was testing my authantication ,i got my jsonwebtoken(from postman after applying post request).Now when i set my header key as:x-auth-token and its value as jwtwebtoken(that i got from postman),instead of getting same data stored in mongodb data base with an id,it shows me just a boolean value "false".no error showing in console.i am not surewhere i am going wrong.please help*

**middleware auth.js file**

```
const jwt=require("jsonwebtoken");
const config=require("config");

module.exports=function(req,res,next){
    //get token from header
    const token=req.header("x-auth-token");

    //check if not token
    if(!token){
       return res.status(401).json({msg:"No token authorization"});

    }
    //verify token
    try{
const decoded=jwt.verify(token,config.get("jwtSecret"));
req.user=decoded.user;
next();
    }catch(err){
res.status(401).json({msg:"Token is not valid"});
    }
} ;
```

**route api auth.js file**

```
const express=require("express");
const router=express.Router();
const auth =require('../../middleware/auth');

const User = require('../../models/User');


//@route  Get api/auth
//does    test route
//@acess Public
router.get("/",auth,async (req,res) =>{
    try{
        const user=await User.findById(req.user.id).selected("-password");
        res.json(user);

    }catch(err){
        console.error(err.message);
        res.status(500).send("server error");

    }
});

module.exports=router;
```

*this is the url on which i am getting "false" on sending get request from postman*

Comment: forget to add url:http://localhost:5000/api/auth

Answer (score 0):

*No one answered this question. After doing a lot of brainstorming, I finally got the answer. Inside my json file add another field for the password like shown below*

```
password:{
          select:false
}
```